# Replace-by-fee issue

Tags: blockchain

Ok so i recieved a 50$ transaction and it was on my account ( the bottom transaction) and 2 days later i have 0 $ on account and all funds from that transaction apparently got replaced by fee, am i gonna get it back eventually or , what does this mean,  i tried googling it but language barrier is kinda messing up things for me[image]

Answer (score 1):

'Replace By Fee' (RBF) is a method of increasing the fee rate for a yet-unconfirmed transaction. As a user, if you send a transaction and then realize the fee-rate was set to low, you can utilize RBF to create a replacement transaction which includes a larger fee, in the hopes of quicker confirmation.

In this case, it looks like there was an RBF-enabled transaction that paid those funds to the `18dC...` address mentioned in your screenshot. This transaction would otherwise be a normal bitcoin transaction, that just has the 'RBF flag' enabled so that it can be replaced if the user so desires.

If you did not create this transaction, then you should consider the fact that the machine your bitcoin wallet is running on is infected with some sort of malware. Without more info, its not really possible to say for certain what happened here though.